# PHP - Write To MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

I'm simply writing some values to a MySQL database using the following snippets of code.

Please note, when I run **SELECT** queries, information is correctly displayed using echo etc.

However when I try to write to the database using **INSERT**, the code executes with no errors, but when I check my database there is nothing written to it.

```
 private $db;

 function __construct() {
 $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'xyz', '123', 'testdb');
 $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);

if (isset($_POST["ID"]) && isset($_POST["Number"]) && isset($_POST["Address"]) && isset($_POST["Ticket"])) {

$id= $_POST["ID"];
$number= $_POST["Number"];
$address= $_POST["Address"];
$ticket= $_POST["Ticket"];

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO tickets (ID, Number, Address, Ticket) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iiss", $id, $number, $address, $ticket);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close()

return true
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Question - Could it be something to do with write access to the database? I've checked the user account privileges and it has all privileges.

Comment: are you sure there's no errors? you don't have any code to output errors, and if error reporting is turned off in your setup you'd never be able to see it. are you checking logs?

Comment: also, there's a couple of semicolons missing at the end

Comment: can you run  the insert query without the `bind_params` (with inline params )?

Comment: I meant syntax errors ie. there was nothing wrong with the php code itself. I've been using Curl to POST data to the above code, which I knew was working because the 'if' statement was returning true. As highlighted below the problem was the auto_commit parameter. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: d.raev - I believe I tried doing that among many other things with no luck. Auto_Commit = TRUE has solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the insert auto_commit must be TRUE.

```
$this->db->autocommit(TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've disabled autocommitting (`$this->db->autocommit(FALSE);`), and you're not committing anywhere explicitly. Once you close the connection, anything you inserted will be rollbacked, as if you never changed the database. Once you're done inserting, you should add a call to `$this->db->commit()`.

Comment: Thank you for your input Mureinik. Yourself/Lucas are both correct, that was indeed the problem.